# DSE Graph from Java - cannot access DelegatingCluster

Tags: java, graph, datastax, datastax-enterprise-graph

The following code snippet tries to connect to Graph and perform some operations on it. It is intended to run using DSE Java driver 1.1, for Graph.

```
import com.datastax.driver.dse.graph.GraphStatement; 
import com.datastax.driver.dse.graph.SimpleGraphStatement; 
import com.datastax.driver.dse.DseCluster; 
import com.datastax.driver.dse.DseSession;

public class GraphTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start...");

        DseCluster dseCluster = DseCluster.builder()
                    .addContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
                    .build();
        DseSession dseSession = dseCluster.connect();dseSession.executeGraph("system.graph('demo').ifNotExists().create()");

        GraphStatement s1 = new SimpleGraphStatement("g.addV(label, 'test_vertex')").setGraphName("demo");      
        dseSession.executeGraph(s1);

        GraphStatement s2 = new SimpleGraphStatement("g.V()").setGraphName("demo");         
        GraphResultSet rs = dseSession.executeGraph(s2);

        System.out.println(rs.one().asVertex());
        System.out.println("End."); 
    }
}
```

However, compilation gives the following error:

> javac -cp .\dse-driver-1.1.0.jar GraphTest.java
>
> GraphTest.java:12: error: cannot access DelegatingCluster
>                   DseCluster dseCluster = DseCluster.builder()
>                                                     ^   class file for com.datastax.driver.core.DelegatingCluster not found
>   GraphTest.java:16: error: cannot access Session
>                   DseSession dseSession = dseCluster.connect();dseSession.executeGraph("system.graph('demo').ifNotExists().create()");
>                                                                          ^   class file for com.datastax.driver.core.Session not found
>   GraphTest.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
>                   GraphResultSet rs = dseSession.executeGraph(s2);
>                   ^   symbol:   class GraphResultSet   location: class GraphTest 3 errors

Which looks like something wrong accessing the classes for setting up the session. Is there anything missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Get the dependencies from Maven and it will do it.

Check:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver-dse//1.1.0/